Jetpack Compose + Room database crashes during recompose after deleting the underlying data
I have Liability and Expense Android Room objects. Each Liability has an optional Expense. I have a LiabilityWithExpense POJO data class that is used by Android Room to select the Liability data (required) and Expense data (optional) in a joined query so I can get it all at once.
I've got a ViewLiability composable. I pass it the Android Room database id for the Liability database row. I collect the LiabilityWithExpense as state:
val liabilityWithExpense by liabilityViewModel.getFullLiabilityById(liabilityId).collectAsState(LiabilityWithExpense.placeholder())

The LiabilityWithExpense.placeholder() just a LiabilityWithExpense object with placeholder data so that the liabilityWithExpense object isn't optional. (I've tried making that liabilityWithExpense optional, but then my UI doesn't automatically recompose when I change the underlying data.)
On the ViewLiability screen, the user can do stuff and tap a Button that will eventually delete the object and then immediately pop the nav stack.
suspend fun finishPayoff() {
    liabilityViewModel.delete(liabilityWithExpense.liability)

    navController.popBackStack()
}

But before the screen is popped off the nav stack, it is recomposed and my liabilityWithExpense state variable becomes null since the underlying database row has been deleted, and the UI code crashes while trying to access that non-optional var that has a null in it.
How can I delete my underlying data and pop the nav stack without the screen recomposing and crashing?
Or am I approaching this the wrong way from the start? Is there some standard pattern I should be using?
FYI, I have already tried to read through other questions and found Jetpack Compose Room Database Flow, deleting item from database causes recompose which asks almost exactly my same question, but the answer provided is about list-of-users situation and how that deleted user will just not be there anymore. But that's not the actual question at hand, because that question (and my question) aren't on the List portion of the UI. We're on a screen for ViewingASingleObject and that object gets deleted.
